# merge two pyspark dataframe based on one column containing list and other as values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have two tables

```
+-----+-----+
|store|sales|
+-----+-----+
|    F| 4000|
|    M| 3000|
|    A| 4000|
+-----+-----+`

+-----+------+
|  upc| store|
+-----+------+
|40288|[F, M]|
|42114|   [M]|
|39192|[F, A]|
+-----+------+`
```

I wish to have the final table as

```
+-----+------+-----+
|  upc| store|sales|
+-----+------+-----+
|40288|[F, M]| 7000|
|42114|   [M]| 3000|
|39192|[F, A]| 8000|
+-----+------+-----+
```

Please use this code for data frame generation

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql import *


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkByExamples.com").getOrCreate()

data2 = [
    ("F", 4000),
    ("M", 3000),
    ("A", 4000),
]
schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("store", StringType(), True),
        StructField("sales", IntegerType(), True),
    ]
)
df11 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2, schema=schema)


data3 = [
    ("40288", ["F", "M"]),
    ("42114", ["M"]),
    ("39192", ["F", "A"]),
]
schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("upc", StringType(), True),
        StructField("store", StringType(), True),
    ]
)
df22 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data3, schema=schema)
```

I can make this work using loops but it will be very inefficient for big_data.  I have this piece of code with loops for pandas data frame but now migrating to Pyspark, so need an equivalent in Pyspark. is there a better way to do without loops to get final_table as shown above?

```py
for i, row in df22.iterrows():
    new_sales = df11[df11.store.isin(df22[df22.upc == row.upc]["store"].values[0])][
        "sales"
    ].sum()
    df22.at[i, "sales"] = new_sales
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying a little bit your input because `df22["store"]` is of type Array(String) in your sample:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, ArrayType


data3 = [
    ("40288", ["F", "M"]),
    ("42114", ["M"]),
    ("39192", ["F", "A"]),
]
schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("upc", StringType(), True),
        StructField("store", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
    ]
)
df22 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data3, schema=schema)
```

df22 is more coherent :

```py
df22.show()
+-----+------+                                                                  
|  upc| store|
+-----+------+
|40288|[F, M]|
|42114|   [M]|
|39192|[F, A]|
+-----+------+

df22.printSchema()
root
 |-- upc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- store: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

From that data, I explode the store, use it to join, then aggregate on upc to recreate the store as list and generate the sales.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


df = (
    df22.withColumn("store", F.explode("store"))
    .join(df11, on="store")
    .groupBy("upc")
    .agg(F.collect_list("store").alias("store"), F.sum("sales").alias("sales"))
)
```

and the result :

```py
df.show()
+-----+------+-----+                                                            
|  upc| store|sales|
+-----+------+-----+
|42114|   [M]| 3000|
|40288|[F, M]| 7000|
|39192|[F, A]| 8000|
+-----+------+-----+

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- upc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- store: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- sales: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: @Chris I fixed the data type in my answer

Comment: it worked, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can `join` based on  [`array_contains`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains.html?highlight=array_contains). After join, group by `upc` and `store` in df22 and `sum` sales.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df11_with_df22 = df11.join(df22, F.array_contains(df22["store"], df11["store"]))

df11_with_df22.groupBy(df22["upc"], df22["store"]).agg(F.sum("sales").alias("sales")).show()
```

### Output

```
+-----+------+-----+
|  upc| store|sales|
+-----+------+-----+
|40288|[F, M]| 7000|
|39192|[F, A]| 8000|
|42114|   [M]| 3000|
+-----+------+-----+
```

Comment: thanks, it worked when store is stringtype. However, it failed when store is arraytype

Comment: Yes since in the question the snippet was parsing array as via `StructField("store", StringType(), True)` , I assumed that's how the data looks liked like, however I believe this was a typo now and you are looking for array check. Updated answer to reflect this.